# Improving scroll performance in iScroll with large images

Tags: javascript, css, web-applications, iscroll

I did notice that when using long pages, using iScroll, but I believe any other js/css code,
the scroll gets choppy...sometimes gets stuck..

I wonder if that is a problem of the images..they are too big (retina) or shoudl i adopt a lazy loading if does really affect a web app..

anybody have the same experience and solved it?

Comment: U wrote hjarntorget?

Answer (score 0):

Which iScroll? iScroll4 or iScroll5?
Usually iScroll get's more and more choppy the more complex your markup and/or CSS is. Especially when using box-shadow or gradients.
On iScroll5 there are some tricks to improve performance like:

**shrinkScrollbars: 'clip'** //do not shrink, just move it out of the container

**useTransition: false,** //use rAnimFrame instead of CSS3 - this increases performance

**bindToWrapper: true,** //bind the scroll event to the wrapper not the whole document

**bounce: false,** //do not perform a bounce on scrollEnd

**fadeScrollbars: false** //make it dependend upon the used device - Android is getting choppy on fade`